# How can I update a bool in a .h file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ok, so I'm making a game for a class project and I have two files: `game.cpp` and a `game.h`. I declared all of my private variables and public functions and I'm currently defining them in the `.cpp` file.

In the menu function, I have this switch:

```
switch (option) {
case 1:

    while (this->playing) {
        //clean screen
        h.screen();

        //deletescroll bar
        h.nosc();

        //draw canvas
        h.draw();


    } 
}
```

Here's my `draw` function:

```
void Game::draw() {
    HWND window= GetConsoleWindow();

    MoveWindow(window, 400, 100, 750, 550, TRUE);
    Game h;



    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    this->columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    this->rows = csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;

    h.nosc();

    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    this->columns = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    this->rows= csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;*/

    gotoxy(15, 0);
    cout << "Lives: " << lives;

    gotoxy(45, 0);
    cout << "Level: " << this->level;

    gotoxy(75, 0);
    cout << "Score: " << this->score;

    //up - down
    for (int i = 2; i < this->columns - 1; i++) {

        gotoxy(i, 1);
        printf("%c", 205);
        //down
        gotoxy(i, this->rows - 1);
        printf("%c", 205);
    }

    //left - right
    for (int j = 2; j < this->rows - 1; j++) {
        gotoxy(2, j);
        printf("%c", 186);
        gotoxy(this->columns - 1, j);
        printf("%c", 186);
    }


    gotoxy(2, 1); 
    printf("%c", 201);
    gotoxy(2, this->rows - 1); 
    printf("%c", 200);
    gotoxy(this->columns - 1, 1);
    printf("%c", 187);
    gotoxy(columns - 1, rows - 1);
    printf("%c", 188);

    this->playing = false;
}
```

It should return to the switch and, since `playing` now's false, it shouldn't run again, correct? But it's still going in and I'm not sure what to do. This is my header `(.h)` file:

```
#pragma once

#include<Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Game {

private:
    int xAxis= 25;
    int yAxis = 25;
    int direction = 0;
    int columns = 0;
    int rows = 0;
    int lives = 3;
    int level = 1;
    int score = 0;
    int scoreArr[9];    
    bool playing;

private:
```

I know this code might look like a mess to some, but I'm still learning. I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: since you are calling for h object it will update the playing flag of h object.. Not current object. either explicitly make this->playing here. or pass this pointer to draw function to make it true inside the draw function.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. One note though: "in a .h file" isn't something you should worry about, because it can have several meanings or be irrelevant. Anyhow, your MCVE will only be one file, so that won't be an issue.

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the "current" object. There may be more than one object in the program, and `this->playing` may refer to different things at different times. It is impossible to tell without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an object named `h`, you can fix your your code like following. You should not check playing variable in this.

```
while (h.playing) {
    //clean screen
    h.screen();

    //deletescroll bar
    h.nosc();

    //draw canvas
    h.draw();
}
```

PS: If you update your question based on [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I will update my answer too.

Comment: So I updated the question but I then tried with `h.playing` and it worked! I know exactly what was happening now, . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly 'h' object is, but the line  `this->playing = false;` inside `h.draw` will access a different variable or different instance of `playing` on `while (this->playing)`inside menu function. If what you need is to end the loop just after completing the `h.draw`, why do you even need the while loop ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The draw function is not finished yet - once it's done it will need one. I was just testing :). But still, `h.playing` is working now for me.